# Safe to delete Google's Update folder?

Tags: windows-7, google-updates

I am on Windows 7. This folder is located in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google`. WinDirStat tells me that it is currently 3.1GB in size! Is this some sort of temporary update folder that I can delete the contents of?

Comment: this is such a joke. 5.3GB for mine!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is safe to delete all old Chrome versions from that hierarchy, though it is policy to keep the last two.

Chrome ought to do this itself, but fails on occasions.

You do not need to clear any other browser caching (unfortunately, the first answer posted seems to have persuaded you to do that, unnecessarily :(

Path to backup versions is
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application`
or to type in Start without fiddling with hidden folders…
`%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\Application`

Comment: I deleted all but the latest 3 folders (which I assume are the versions). Nothing was locked when I deleted them and nothing has blown up yet so I assume that it was successful! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the thanks - though the SE way to say thank you is to upvote the answer (&/or question) if you found them useful.

Answer (score -2):

That folder contains your Google Chrome data. If this is taking up too much space it's best to clear the cache via Google Chrome itself ( https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en ) :

- In the top-right corner of Chrome, click the Chrome menu Chrome Menu.
- Select More tools > Clear browsing data.
- In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
- Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. - Select beginning of time to delete everything.
- Click Clear browsing data

Comment: I did what you suggested and there was no change that I saw. I drilled down further to the C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Update\Install directory and I see 120+ folders that are around 40MB each. Could those be deleted?

Comment: That sounds very strange. That folder is located in my Program Files (x86) but that could perhaps be because you installed in a different folder. The folders on my pc are around 1MB each, can you check the content of a 40MB folder?