# Google Chrome app file in Mac is 22GB large

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I was looking around the web and was told that if I have too many older versions that I should delete them. Can you guys confirm that? I noticed that when I open the package contents, the Versions folder is storing a massive amount of data as shown in the pic here:

[image: Version]

and the versions inside look like this

[image]

Edit: How many versions do you suggest I keep? Just the newest version or a few of the other ones as well?

Comment: In windows Google Chrome keep two version current and previous. You can delete this folder if you don't want them.

But i suggest you not to delete current and previous version.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm gonna keep the last 4 versions just in case. It turns out I had a ton of versions stashed and caused it to amount to a whopping 20 GB of storage. What an immense waste of space! All this time I was wondering what else I could be wasting my storage on. Looks like I found the answer here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Policy is to keep the last 2 versions; which it ought to do itself, but sometimes messes up. I'd delete all but the last 2 then keep an eye on it for a while & see if it stays that way.

This is my current folder contents -

[image]

For future Googlers, to access the contents of the Google Chrome app, right click it & select 'Show Package Contents'.

See [Safe to delete Google's Update folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/914246/safe-to-delete-googles-update-folder/914297#914297) for the Windows equivalent.